# PHP DateTime class Namespace

Tags: php, datetime, namespaces

I'm using the symfony2 framework and I want to use the PHP's DateTime class (PHP version is 5.3).

Here the declaration:

```
namespace SDCU\GeneralBundle\Entity;

class Country
{
   public function __construct(){
       $this->insertedAt = new DateTime();
   }
}
```

But, when executing this constructor, I get an error saying that there's no "SDCU\GeneralBundle\Entity\DateTime" class. I've been searching around for DateTime's namespace but with no success... any idea?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`DateTime` is in the global namespace, and as "[class names always resolve to the current namespace name](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)" you have to use `\DateTime`.

Or import the package using:

```
use \Datetime;
```

Comment: You could also put `use \Datetime;` between the namespace and the class declaration, and keep on using `DateTime`. another point: this also goes for `Exception`! Catching `Exception` where you should catch `\Exception` doesn't give an error, you're just not catching anything!

Answer (score 23):

Better solution for using classes in global namespaces is "use" keyword instead of "\" before class.

```
namespace SDCU\GeneralBundle\Entity;
use \DateTime;

class Country
{
   public function __construct(){
       $this->insertedAt = new DateTime();
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be ```use \DateTime```, not ```use DateTime```.

Comment: If you ever have a class in the local namespace with the same name as one in the global namespace, you _have_ to prefix `\\`, or you'll just be importing the local class.

Comment: I like this, reminds me of other languages like Python in a way, when you need to use a class that is part of the core you bring it in with `use` that looks clean IMO